# ng add @scullyio/init acts like it's fine in terminal until I choose Puppeteer

Tags: angular, scully

I cannot get `ng add @scullyio/init` to generate the needed config.ts file. I recreated the issue on the following fresh project. Nothing is created after choosing Puppetter.

The package @scullyio/init@2.1.36 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
? Which route renderer would you like to use? Puppeteer

brian@DESKTOP-9CFSHDE MINGW64 ~/scullydemo (master)

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to generate home module in your angular app to create entry-point for Scully, `ng generate module home --route home --module app`
Then, add the Scully `ng add @scullyio/init`